# Do I need use inheritance for react components?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have 2 components which get props some array of objects. 
This array of objects I generate before render this components. If array of objects is empty, I don't need those components show.

I have event listener which change my array. So I don't want add this event listener in each component. How can I optimize this?

```
class First extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      array: props.array
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    element.addEventListener('change', () => {
       this.setState({ array: newArray })
    }
  }

  render() {
    if (this.state.array.length >0) {
       return 'First'
    }
  }
}

class Second extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      array: props.array
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    element.addEventListener('change', () => {
       this.setState({ array: newArray })
    }
  }

  render() {
    if (this.state.array.length >0) {
       return 'Second'
    }
  }
}


const array = initializeArray()
const form = document.querySelector("form[action='/add']")
render(<First array={array} />, form);
render(<Second array={array} />, document.body);
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are looking for conditional rendering which in your case would be:

```
render({ array.length && <First array={array} /> }, form);
render({ array.length && <Second array={array} /> }, document.body);
```

Answer (score 0):

For the array empty condition you could use a [ternary conditional operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator), the safe operation is to test the existence and the emptiness of the array:

```
array && array.length > 0 ? <First array={array} /> : undefine
```

For the event listener, you could implement it in a third component that is above the other two you already have, and this component would manage the state of the array and pass it by props to the other components.

You could also use a library to make it easier, using the [react-globally](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-globally) you could set states globally and access them form anywhere. Using the ternary option but with the `this.props.globalState.array` you won't even need the `componentDidMount`.

Comment: I can't use third component because `First` and `Second` renders in different places. 

Thanks, I will take a look on react-globaly